# Mapping host name Zend2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have developed a site recently which home page opens when i hit [this url](http://www.ghtclasses.com/ght/public/)  but i want to open my site home page when user hit only this [link](http://www.ghtclasses.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your apache vhost configuration and set the `DocumentRoot` to `ght/public/`

Answer (score 0):

If you only have access to the **data** directory, but not to the apache config itself, you can add a `.htaccess` with contents (must be allowed by the server):

```
RedirectMatch 301 /(.*) /ght/public$1
```

Alternatively, why don't you upload your PHP and HTML files directly into the webserver root? (above the /ght/public/ directory) What access to you have to the webserver?